# How to create separate cross table from list

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, crosstable

I want to separate the cross table from single to multiple accprding to the given column list against the last column(CLASS).
THE DATA IN THE TABLE LOOKS LIKE

```
GND  | BRD | ERS | CLASS
 F   |  A  |  AB |  ON
 M   |  D  |  CB |  ON
 M   |  S  |  AV |  ON
 F   |  S  |  AV |  OFF
 M   |  S  |  CB |  ON
```

This means that the last column against first column, last column agasinst next column

tried

```
#after loading dataframe
 g = pandas....
 #now
 idx = [g.GND g.BRD, g.ERS]     
    def cross_tb(inx):
        dt = pd.crosstab(inx,   g.CLASS)
        return dt   
    cross_tb(idx)
```

THIS GIVES SINLE TABLE WHICH LOOK LIKE

```
       F  M  A  D  S  AB  AV  CB
CLASS                           
OFF    1  0  0  0  1   0   1   0
ON     1  3  1  1  2   1   1   2
```

But I want to separate them once against CLASS one by one table like

```
  First one output      
    CLASS OFF ON  PERCENTAGE                          
    F     1   1     20%
    M     0   3     30%
  second output  A AND D etc..
```

But if you do this

```
 dt = pd.crosstab(g.GND,   g.CLASS)
```

it gives single column until you write the line again with other column

Comment: Please give an example of your data and expected results.

Comment: Please include your expected output as a table.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can save the results of the `crosstab` to a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {c: pd.crosstab(df[c], df["CLASS"]) for c in df.columns if c!="CLASS"}

>>> df_dict["GND"]
CLASS  OFF  ON
GND           
F        1   1
M        0   3
```

Comment: @not_special this gives a single combined but also i get the same thing on my code above, I want to separate the please read the question

Comment: You did not provide your expected output. How do you expect to save/display 3 different tables. Do you want to create a list of DataFrames? Or just print the results without saving?

Comment: @not_special I want 3 separate table but  without duplicating the cross tab function

Comment: So just save it to a `list` or `dict`. See the edit.